# How to create four blanks would be filled in this order

Tags: javascript

```
"The ______ ______ looked around ______ then ______ into the house"
```

how to create four blanks would be filled in this order: (adjective) (noun) (adverb) (verb) in javascript.

```
EX: wordBlanks("dog", "big", "ran", "quickly")
```

Comment: Please describe more about your question

Answer (score 1):

you can use [`template literral`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```js
let wordBlanks = (word1, word2, word3, word4) => {
  return `The ${word1} ${word2} looked around ${word3} then ${word4} into the house`
}

console.log( wordBlanks("dog", "big", "ran", "quickly") )
```

---

if you really need the `____` in input you can use [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/String/replace) in a loop (also this one is more generic so it may be better depending on your needs)

```js
let sentence = "The ____ _____ looked around ____ then ______ into the house"
let fillers = ["dog", "big", "ran", "quickly"]

while (sentence.includes('_')) {
  sentence = sentence.replace(/_+/, fillers.shift())
  // /_+/ is a regex (see mdn link below) which looks for a group of underscores
}

console.log(sentence)
// take care it destroies the fillers array
console.log(fillers)
```

[`mdn link for regex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

[`mdn link for Array.shift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift)

Comment: Neat solution, however it assumes that there are always four blanks.

Comment: @AnisR. yeah and it assumes the sentence never change, that's why I updated with a second more generic solution

Answer (score 1):

You could use empty `<span>` elements for that, and fill them using their `innerHTML` property.

This is a solution that scales to whatever number of blanks you have:

```js
function fillBlanks(words) {
  //here "words" is an array of words
  
  var blanks = document.getElementsByClassName("blank");
  
  //checking that the number of words in the list matches the number of blanks
  if(words.length != blanks.length) {
    console.log("Number of words does not match number of blanks");
    return;
  }
  
  for(var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    blanks[i].innerHTML = words[i];
  }
}

var words = ["word1", "word2", "word3", "word4"];
fillBlanks(words);
```

```html
<p>The <span class="blank"></span> <span class="blank"></span> looked around <span class="blank"></span>then <span class="blank"></span> into the house</p>
```

Comment: op never said he wanted to show the result in HTML, but a clean solution anyways

Comment: @ThilinaWilliams You're welcome! If this post answered your question, consider marking it as the answer.